# Netbeans and sourceforge git repository: Why I can't see update file online

Tags: git, netbeans, sourceforge

I have a remote repository upon sourceforge Git space. I clone this repository on local machine make some editing and then upload the change.

```
git add C:\...\default.ctp
git commit -m comment C:\...\default.ctp
Commit Log
revision   : 89......08
author     : m**** <user@domain.com>
date       : 11-ago-2012 17.52.21
summary    : comment
```

This is the netbeans response, so everything seems ok. But If go online in my code tree of sourceforge site, default.ctp isn't update, matter of fact the commit number is the same as every other file. Why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you commit, then that commit is only in your local repository. If you want that commit in your Soureforge repository, you have to push your commits. With command line, the command is something like this:

```
git push origin branchname
```